# Vim display wchar text properly

Tags: vim, encoding

I'm trying to look at a file that was saved without a BOM as wchar text. In my gVim window I see:

```
T^@E^@X^@T^@H^@E^@R^@
```

...which is really annoying. I want to edit this file as a regular text document, and I'd like vim to save it in the same format. I've tried doing `:set encoding=utf-16` (and other variations such as `utf-16le`, `ucs-2`, and `ucs-2le`, but the document view never changes. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: did you try something like: "set fenc=UTF-8/latin1" already?

Comment: @Hypnos, I tried everything written above with both `encoding` and `fileencoding`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reload the file with the appropriate encoding:

```
:e ++enc=utf-16
```